# Conjugate gradient descent when $A$ is non-singular but not symmetric

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, convex-optimization, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

> If $A$ is a non-singular matrix that is not symmetric, will the $k$th update of CGD still yield an optimal guess $x_{k+1}$ for the system $Ax = b$?

Using the update rule $x_{k+1} = x_k + \alpha_k p_k,$ for $p_k$ the $k$th conjugate basis vector, CGD uses $\alpha_k = \frac{(b - Ax_k)^Tp_k}{p_k^TAp_k}$ to minimize $f(x_{k+1}) = x_{k+1}^TAx_{k+1} - 2b^Tx_{k+1}.$ When will CGD still compute the optimal $x_{k+1}$ here? Is there a straightforward example of CGD's update rule failing for a matrix $A$ that is non-singular, but just not symmetric?

Comment: @userrandrand One of the conjugate basis vectors, following notation from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method#Derivation_as_a_direct_method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CG does not converge to a solution, e.g., for $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\text{ and } b=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$
The solution is $x=[0, 1]^T$, but CG stagnates at $x_k=[2/3, 2/3]^T$ starting from the first iteration, not by accident at the solution of the system with the matrix $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the example. Is there any nice, general constraint to ensure CG will converge for a non-symmetric matrix, or is it always the case that it will stagnate?

Comment: @jackyooo I recall there was a [paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0721026) characterizing matrices for which a short term CG-like recurrence exists. I'm not aware though of one (though perhaps there is one) investigating towards what CG converges (if towards anything at all) with a nonsymmetric matrix plugged in.